# Linux kernel - check currently used drivers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Is it possible to check what drivers from linux kernel source are used for currently working devices in the system? I know that usually device drivers are written as kernel modules, but some of them have cryptic names and I would want to see if there is some listing that would say: deviceA : moduleA (or inform me that driver was built to the kernel during compilation)

I need to modify some source code of current hardware drivers and I was wondering what is the easiest way to pinpoint exactly which drivers my hardware is using.

To be exact I wanted to know what drivers are used by my keyboard, mouse, hard drive and network card.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all currently running modules by running using `lsmod`. To retrieve information about a module and assosiated devices, etc, simply run `modinfo <ModuleName>`

To see which driver is loaded for each particular device, the easiest is to run `hwinfo`. The command gives a lot of information, also not driver related info. For a overview you should run it as `hwinfo --short`